# query in two or three fields elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have the query below that searches simultaneously in three fields (title, url and description) in my index.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "pgrk": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "url_length": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "netflix releases",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "url",
        "description"
      ],
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to search in just two fields and if don't find anything, search in the third field too? that is, I wanted to search only in the fields (title and url) and if I can't find anything, search the three fields (title, url and Description)

My query sorts the results by the field (pagerank) and by the field (url_length) cannot remove the ordering by the field (pagerank and url_length) because this ordering is important for my results. With this sorting that I do it does not generate (_score), if it generated score I would put (boost) in the fields (title and url) to give relevance to these two fields,  but as there is no score, I need a way to search in two relevant fields and if don't find anything, search the three fields

Comment: Did you tried using bool queries? Link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: @Harshit in the Boolean query can consult in only two fields and if find nothing search in three fields? i am new with elasticsearch. Would you like to help me showing how the query would look?